OnPropertyChanged not working correctly in Blazor (MAUI Hybrid)
I've registered a service in MauiProgram.cs:
builder.Services.AddSingleton<NetworkStatusService>();

the service class:
public class NetworkStatusService : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private NetwStatus _netwStat;
    public NetwStatus NetwStat
    {
        get => _netwStat;
        set
        {
            if (_netwStat != value)
            {
                _netwStat = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(NetwStat));
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public async Task CheckNetw()
    {
        NetwStat = NetwStatus.Loading;

        await Task.Delay(1000);

        if (await SomeClass.CheckDBConnection())
            NetwStat = NetwStatus.Success;
        else
            NetwStat = NetwStatus.Fail;
    }
}

my simplified blazor page would be as below:
@page "/LoginComponent"
<div class="Grid">
    @switch (NetworkStatusService.NetwStat)
    {
        case NetwStatus.Loading:
            <h6 style="font-size:0.8rem; margin-bottom:-12px; color:coral">Trying to connect...</h6>
            break;
        case NetwStatus.Success:
            <h6 style="font-size:0.8rem; margin-bottom:-12px; color:green">Connected uccessfully.</h6>
            break;
        case NetwStatus.Fail:
            <h6 style="font-size:0.8rem; margin-bottom:-12px; color:red">Connection failed.</h6>
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }    ‌ ‌
    <i @onclick="ViewModel.btnNetwOkCommand.ExecuteAsync">refresh</i>
</div>

the command would obviously run NetworkStatusService.CheckNetw()
but it NEVER changes to the "Trying to connect..." mode. it just waits and changes to either success or fail. It's super frustrating, I'm starting to hate my career.

...have you used your step-through debugger to investigate the issue so-far? If so, please tell us exactly what happened inside OnPropertyChanged? If not, why not?

@Dai it's super frustrating, it totally worked as a local property in my ViewModel, but stopped working after I moved it to the service... makes me hate .net, they turn every simple task into a headache for some reason

I appreciate it's frustrating, but you haven't answered my questions...

@Dai I'll try debugging it tomorrow at work and update you asap, thanks for noting that

@Dai haha u answered me so fast I barely got time to type my second comment

You need to wire the component up to the NetworkStatusService event like this:
@page "/"
@using System.ComponentModel
@inject NetworkStatusService NetworkStatusService
@implements IDisposable

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<div class="m-2">
    @switch (NetworkStatusService.NetwStat)
    {
        case NetwStatus.Loading:
            <h6 class="alert alert-warning" >Trying to connect...</h6>
            break;
        case NetwStatus.Success:
            <h6 class="alert alert-success">Connected uccessfully.</h6>
            break;
        case NetwStatus.Fail:
            <h6 class="alert alert-danger">Connection failed.</h6>
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }    ‌ ‌
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="ExecuteAsync">refresh</button>
</div>

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        this.NetworkStatusService.PropertyChanged += OnPropertyChanged;
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(object? sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.InvokeAsync(this.StateHasChanged);
    }

    private async Task ExecuteAsync()
    {
        await NetworkStatusService.CheckNetw();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.NetworkStatusService.PropertyChanged -= OnPropertyChanged;
    }
}

You could also write your service like this:
public class NetworkStatusService
{
    public NetwStatus NetwStat { get; private set; }

    public event EventHandler? NetworkStatusChanged;

    protected virtual void NotifyStatusChanged()
    {
        NetworkStatusChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public async Task CheckNetw()
    {
        this.NetwStat = NetwStatus.Loading;
        this.NotifyStatusChanged();

        await Task.Delay(1000);

        this.NetwStat = NetwStatus.Fail;
        this.NotifyStatusChanged();
    }
}


The perfect answer, thanks! for anyone else in the future wondering what exactly they should add without digging into my code, look at the OnInitialized and Dispose methods only. also you're better off using "protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()" in many cases.

This is exactly why I think INotifyPropertyChanged doesn't work so well with Blazor. This line is the equivalent of an async void:
PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

Since you do not (and cannot) await it the rendering is disconnected from the program flow.
In OnPropertyChanged() you would have to call StateHasChanged() but that's a protected method of the page. Meaning you will need some ugly IView coupling to hand to the ViewModel. And the plumbing to set that up.

oh man you spoke my heart, shouldn't they just fix it? so many unnecessary complications in blazor/maui. changed my code a thousand ways and stayed at work for an extra 4 hours today just to hear "you're behind" tomorrow. I should probably start moving to sth other than .net.

Well, first consider doing Blazor w/o MVVM, or at least w/o INotifyPropertyChanged. Note that I have never used Blazor/MAUI, but I know WPF and XAML. Blazor is a different platform, with simpler binding to data and events. Less abstractions but very usable.  Go with the flow.

Well, not ideal but I added this to my page's OnInitializeAsync:
NetworkStatusService.PropertyChanged += (sender, args) => InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);

and it's working.

That is a relatively clean workaround, I was envisioning something a lot bigger.

I was answering this question while you posted this answer.  See my answer for how to correctly implement this with IDisposable to remove the handler when the component is destroyed.

@MrCakaShaunCurtis thanks! that's exactly how it should be done.

Might be a good idea to remove this answer if you feel that the provided one is a better form of it!
